# String to unsigned long conversion

Tags: arduino-mega, data-type, convert

I'm trying to use `strtoul()` to convert an Arduino **S**tring to an unsigned long *(like the return of `millis();`)* using the following code snippet:

```
unsigned long foo (String time)
{
  unsigned long mili;
  char Tim[9]="";
  uint16_t timsize = time.length()+1;
  char TIM[timsize];
  time.toCharArray(TIM,timsize);
  mili=strtoul(TIM,timsize,10);
  return mili;
}
```

The code seems to work. However, I'm getting the following warning:

> invalid conversion from 'uint16_t {aka unsigned int}' to 'char**' [-fpermissive] `mili=strtoul(TIM,timsize,10);`

---

My question is twofold:

1. Is there a better way to convert a **S**tring to unsigned long without first converting to a C string?
2. If not, how can I eliminate this error?

Comment: [`unsigned long strtoul(const char *str, char **str_end, int base );`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) The 2nd parameter is `char **`. Can be `nullptr`.

Comment: I believe that `char TIM[timsize]` is bad code.  The size of arrays need to be know at compile time and since the value of `time` is not constant its length can't be known.  I think you'd need to do a `new`, if you were still doing it which you aren't because you are using `.c_str()`

Comment: It may be poor code. I do know that it works though (however for a 2D or greater array, only the last value can be a var)

Comment: @CodeGorilla `char TIM[timsize]` usually works on newer compilers:  [Declaring an array with a non-constant size variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3814766/5271927)

Comment: VLAs are not part of the C++ standard. They work here because of a compiler extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arduino `String` class provides method `c_str()`. So you don't have to convert it to C string, as it's already stored as a C string internally.

And as mentioned in comments, the second parameter of `strtoul` is:

> **endptr**
>       Reference to an object of type `char*`, whose value is set by the function to the next character in str after the numerical value.
>       This parameter can also be a null pointer, in which case it is not used.

Basically you can reduce whole foo to the:  `return strtoul(time.c_str(), NULL, 10);`

Comment: Can you tell me more about how to access the `c_str()` method of a **S**tring? just using `sec=strtoul(tim,endptr,10);` did not work.

Comment: @ATE-ENGE Added to the answer.

Comment: Also be aware that `strtol()` can return 0 or ULONG_MAX if there is a problem, so the calling function should check for these because if you do a `delay(ULONG_MAX);` you'll think it has locked up :)

Comment: @CodeGorilla That would be a problem! Hypothetically, is there a good way to differentiate if a problem occurs? You know, in case a user actually does want to halt the program for 50 days :)

Comment: @ATE-ENGE You can use that endptr to check if whole string was parsed. However it returns 0 if there is nothing to parse and ULONG_MAX if the value is out of range so it must be even bigger than 32bit number.

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFF in decimal is 10 digits, and you were looking at 9 for the size of `Tim[]` so you could have an issue.  You could look at `endptr` or you could enforce sensible limits, i.e. `if (t < 100) t = 100; if (t>100000) t = 100000;`